# Настроить Server Push в Nginx для rel="modulepreload"

Tags: nginx

Я настроил Nginx, как реверс прокси для сервера, а также в соответствии с [официальной документацией Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-9-http2-server-push/) настроил HTTP/2 Server Push.

Конфигурации Server Push блока выглядит примерно так:

```
location / {
      http2_push_preload on;
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0;
}
```

Nginx перехватывает Link хедер от сервера и пушит ресурсы, если для них указано rel="preload". Это работает отлично, но на ресурсе используются javascript модули, и для их предзагрузки [оптимально](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/modulepreload/) использовать не preload, а [modulepreload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/modulepreload). Проблема в том, что Nginx не пушит ресурсы для rel="modulepreload", а только если rel="preload", поэтому здесь вопрос - есть ли какой-то способ сделать так, чтоб Nginx пушил ресурсы указанные с modulepreload? Например как-то перехватывать самостоятельно перехватывать HTTP-заголовок Link ответа и использовать директиву http2_push для того, чтоб запушить ресурсы?

Так же прикрепляю скрины, на которых в Chrome Dev Tools видно, что css-ресурсы, для которых указано rel="preload" успешно пушатся, а javascript файлы, для которых стоит rel="modulepreload" - нет.[image: HTTP-заголовок Link с настройками для предзагрузки] [image: Вкладка Network, на которой видно, что ресурсы не пушатся]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не то чтобы я нашел ответ на вопрос, но я обнаружил, что поддержка HTTP/2 Server Push [будет убрана](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/removing-push/) из будущих версий браузеров, поэтому в ответе на вопрос больше нет необходимости